# Unable to get Excel to generate an email

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

When I run my macro to create an email it stops at the first step I have checked the libraries and MS Office and MS Outlook are checked,

With code ;

```
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
```

I recieve the error user-defined type not defined

and with code ;

```
Dim OutlookApp As Object
Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

I recieve

> active x could not create the object

I have tried running as admin and with outlook closed and opened, still can not get it to create the messeage.

Comment: Have you set a Reference to "Microsoft Outlook XX Object Library"?

Comment: The reference to "Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object Library" is checked

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" _
Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, _
ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long


Dim Email As String, Subj As String
Dim answer As Integer
Dim Msg As String, body As String, URL As String
Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object

 Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

 On Error Resume Next
     With OutMail
         .To = Email
         .CC = vbNullString
         .BCC = vbNullString
         .Subject = Subj
         .body = body
         .Display
     End With
 On Error GoTo 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two working solutions for you:

```
Public Sub UsingEarlyBinding()

'A reference to the Microsoft Outlook XX Object Library is
'necessary to run this code (as mentioned by @gizlmeier)

Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objEmail As Object

Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set objEmail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
objEmail.Display

End Sub
```

.

```
Public Sub UsingLateBinding()

'No references are necessary to run this code

Dim OutlookApp As Object
Dim objEmail As Object

Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objEmail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

objEmail.Display

End Sub
```

The advantage of using the first solution is that you get to see a drop-down menu in the VBE (while writing the code) offering you auto-completion. That's due to the fact that the VBE recognizes (with the reference) the Outlook library and can offer auto-completions from that library. Example:

[image]

Comment: Still recieve " Error 429 activex could not create object"

Comment: Since no creation of any ActiveX element is involved in the above code I am assuming that you might have some Add-Ins running doing some extra stuff or preventing certain things. Try running the above code once you have disabled all Add-Ins (in Outlook and Excel) and you have closed / reopened **all** MS Office applications.